# Use App Pool Identity and User that running process

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, iis, active-directory

I am wanting to know is this possible or what could be a possible workaround.  I want to have my site running in IIS - the App pool that runs the site will be a Service Account that can look up AD.

To get the current App Pool account and set up the Principal context I have the below:

```
string appPoolAccount = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
// Define Context
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

Now users will be running the site from there own machine - when they launch there browser the username that launches the process will be 'test123' as an example - as this would be there logged in user.

What I need to get is that userid that they are running the browser as so I can do something like below (were the second parameter will be the string of the user running the process which I have found):

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context , 'test123');
```

So far I have tried to get that user string from:

```
string test = Environment.UserName; //Took the App Pool Account
WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); // Took App Pool account
string test = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; //bombed out as null
```

Comment: What kind of application it is? ASP.NET? WCF or any other? `HttpContext.Current.User` becomes `null` if you call it on a non request processing thread, which is quite normal.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work, but you have enable Windows Authentication in Web.Config and Disable anonymous authentication.

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: As i mentioned that throws a null exception as if i hit a breakpoint HttpConext.Current.User is NULL.  I have disabled anoymous authentication in IIS - I will double check web config has enable windows auth